# Conditionally terminating a deferred script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm reading a log file for certain patterns like PLAY, PAUSE, STOP, etc..

I want to execute a certain script only when I read a STOP which isn't followed by a PLAY within the next 5 seconds.

Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
tail -Fn0 /tmp/player.log | \
while read line ; do
    echo "$line" | grep -q "PLAYER STATE CHANGE: "
    if [ $? = 0 ]
    then
        # If playing 
        echo "$line" | grep -q "PLAY"
        if [ $? = 0 ]
        then
            echo "Started PLAYING!"
            kill -INT $pid
        fi
        # If paused 
        echo "$line" | grep -q "PAUSE"
        if [ $? = 0 ]
        then
            echo "PAUSED!"
            defer_switch_off.sh &
            pid=$!
        fi
        # If stopped 
        echo "$line" | grep -q "STOP"
        if [ $? = 0 ]
        then
            echo "STOPPED!"
            defer_switch_off.sh &
            pid=$!
        fi
    fi
done
```

And here's my `defer_switch_off.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
trap 'kill -INT $pid' INT
timeout 10 sh -c 'sleep 5; switch_off.sh' &
pid=$!
wait $pid
```

The problem I'm having is that I'm not able to `kill` the `deferred_switch_off.sh` script when a `PLAY` follows a `STOP` within a timespan of 5 seconds as I would like. The script still gets executed.

Comment: Nothing to do with your problem but you could simplify your tests with the `=~` string matching bash operator: `if [[ "$line" =~ "PLAY" ]]; then`.

Comment: Thanks @RenaudPacalet. I didn't know that, will give it a try.

Comment: I know this is not your problem, but you should really implement this as a state machine, having a special state (e.g. STOP_WAIT) that is associated with time checking.

Comment: @MichaelJaros. You're probably right, but the log is written to by a 3rd party app which (although open-source) I'm not willing to recode.

Comment: Are the log lines timestamped (`PLAY` logged 5 seconds after `STOP`), or do you want to cancel it after 5 real seconds have passed?

Comment: Rather than `...|grep ...; if [ $? = 0 ]; then`, just write `if ... | grep ...; then`

Comment: @chepner Although the logs are timestamped, I'm not using the timestamps currently. My approach is to start a script (i.e. `deferred_switch_off.sh`), which will run my script (i.e. `switch_off.sh`) after 5 seconds. I keep note of this pid. Then, if within these 5 seconds a `PLAY` is received, I send `SIGINT` to that pid.

Answer (score 1):

In you script, you need to check how much time has passed since you started `deferred_switch_off.sh` each time you see PLAY after seeing STOP.

```
if [[ $line =~ PLAY ]]; then
    if (( pid && SECONDS < 5 )); then
        kill -INT "$pid"
        unset pid
    fi
elif [[ $line =~ STOP ]]; then
    SECONDS=0
    defer_switch_off.sh &
    pid=$!
elif ...
```

`SECONDS` is a `bash` shell variable that is incremented each second.

---

A different approach is to record the timestamp each time you see STOP, and check the timestamp on the PLAY line if `pid` is non-zero. This could behave differently if you aren't reading the log in real-time.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to give this a try.